# Jinja2 block rendering twice

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a problem when trying to render a Jinja2 block on Flask.
I have this:

**layout.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ES">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block page_title %}{% endblock %} - misitioweb.es</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block page_content %}
        <h1>{% block main_title %}{% endblock %}</h1>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

**register.html**

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block page_title %}Registrarse{% endblock %}
{% block page_content %}
    {{ super() }}
    {% block main_title %}Registrate aquí{% endblock %}
    <form action="/register/" method="post">
        {{ form.username.label }}{{ form.username() }} <br>
        {{ form.email.label }}{{ form.email() }} <br>
        {{ form.password.label }}{{ form.password() }} <br>
        {{ form.password_compare.label }}{{ form.password_compare() }} <br>
        {{ form.accept_tos.label }}{{ form.accept_tos() }} <br>
        {{ form.submit() }}
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**The result is this (this is just an example, no styles at all):**
[image]

As you can see, the main_title block is repeated, first as I wanted to make it, as an H1 title as you can see in layout.html, and then as a simple text as if it were just taking the block on register.html. I used the super() template to keep the h1 that contains the title, inside the content. I just need the H1.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This might do it:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block page_title %}Registrarse{% endblock %}
{% block main_title %}Registrate aquí{% endblock %}
{% block page_content %}
    <form action="/register/" method="post">
        {{ form.username.label }}{{ form.username() }} <br>
        {{ form.email.label }}{{ form.email() }} <br>
        {{ form.password.label }}{{ form.password() }} <br>
        {{ form.password_compare.label }}{{ form.password_compare() }} <br>
        {{ form.accept_tos.label }}{{ form.accept_tos() }} <br>
        {{ form.submit() }}
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: That's what I ended doing.